# Some doubts about how this query is handled in C#?

Tags: c#

I am absolutly new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have a doubt about work the following code.

So in a manager class that perform some operation on a DB table I have something like it:

```
public class UserManager : ManagerDB
{

    // Define the field to select on a t1 database table:
    public const string _sqlElencoUtenti = "SELECT  t1.user_id, t1.my_login, t1.nome, t1.cognome , t1.email,  t1.date_added, t1.date_last_login, t1.is_enabled, t1.customer_id , t1.uidAD ";

    // Return a list of MyUser object filtered according to the values that are contained into a MyUser object
    public List<Models.MyUser> getList(out int totalRecords, Models.MyUser filter, int pageSize = -1, int pageIndex = -1, string sort = "MY_LOGIN", string sortOrder = "ASC")
    {

        List<Models.MyUser> result;
        result= new List<Models.MyUser>();

        // Selection of the interesting fields from UTENTE DB table:
        _strSQL = _sqlElencoUtenti + " FROM UTENTE as t1";

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();

        string strWHERE = "";    // Beginning WHERE condiction

        if (filter != null) {    // If exist a filter object use it to filter the query
            // If the MyUser filter object have the name field that is not null and not empty:
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.nome)){
                // Create the new strWHERE that represent my where condicton
                strWHERE += " AND nome like  @NOME";
                addParameter(command, "@NOME", "%" + filter.nome + "%");
            }

            ................................
            ................................
            ................................
            }
    }
}
```

So I have some doubt about what exactly perform inside the last if of the previous code

It seems to me that if the field **nome** (the name) **MyUser** filter object is not null and not an empty it is used to valorize the **strWHERE** String (that represent the query WHERE condiction).

The 2 things that I can't understand is what is the exact roole of the **@NOME** inside the line

```
strWHERE += " AND nome like  @NOME";
```

and what exactly do this other line:

```
addParameter(command, "@NOME", "%" + filter.nome + "%");
```

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: what code do you have on `addParameter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nome acts as a placeholder. It tells sql that you are going to add an parameter to the query.
The addParameter function then tells the sql command what the parameter should resolve to.

Hope this helps.

Happy C#'ing!!

Answer (score 4):

`@NOME` is a parameter to the query. The `addParameter` replaces the parameter with a formatted value (go to definition of the `addParameter` to see what it does exactly).

Answer (score 1):

There are some major flaws in this code.

1) Why you are declaring query string as `public const` ??

2) You can't pass parameters you are trying to pass.

Use `AddParameter` of Command object.

3) Why you are trying to get results in `List` i think you need to use either `DataSet` or `DataTable` to fill then try to add results to your custom list.

Comment: If you say "Why are you declaring QS as public const", you should also exlain why that is a bad idea. What do you have in mind?

Comment: const keyword is used to declare a constant field or a constant local. This keyword specifies that the value of the field or the local variable is constant. It's not a good practice to use const keyword for declaring sql queries. Because sql may be modified or changed at any time.